# How can I add tails when I eat a food in my console Snake game on Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I created a console snake game and some basics work pretty well. However, I couldn't add the tail feature. Here is my code:

Game.java(Main class)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Game{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    World world = new World(10, 5);
    world.init();
    world.draw();



    while(true){
        //get input 
        char direction = input.next().charAt(0);

        //apply input 
        world.getSnake().direction = direction;

        //simulate 
        world.tick();

        //rendering
        world.draw();
    }
}}
```

World.java

```
public class World{
private char[][] field;
private int width;
private int height;

private Snake snake;

public World(int width, int height){
    //+2 for borders
    this.width  = width + 2;
    this.height = height + 2;

}

public void init(){
    this.field = new char[height][width];

    //background
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            field[y][x] = '.';
        }
    }

    //walls
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        field[0][x]          = '#';
        field[height - 1][x] = '#';
         }

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        field[y][0]         = '#';
        field[y][width - 1] = '#';
    }

    //snake 
    snake = new Snake();
    snake.init(this.width / 2, this.height / 2);
    field[snake.head.y][snake.head.x] = 'o';


    //food
    generateFood();


}

public void tick(){
    field[snake.head.y][snake.head.x] = '.';

    //movement 
    switch(snake.direction){
        case 'w':
            snake.head.y--;
            break;
        case 's':
            snake.head.y++;
            break;
        case 'a':
            snake.head.x--;
            break;
        case 'd':
            snake.head.x++;
            break;

    }


    //logic(rules)
    switch(field[snake.head.y][snake.head.x]){
        case '#':
        case 'o':
            //game over
            init();
            break;
        case '*':
            //eating
            generateFood();
            break;

    }

    field[snake.head.y][snake.head.x] = 'o';

}

public void generateFood(){
    Point food = new Point();
    food.x = (int)(Math.random() * (width - 3))  + 1;
    food.y = (int)(Math.random() * (height - 3)) + 1;

    if(food.x == snake.head.x && food.y == snake.head.y){
        generateFood();
    }
    else{
        field[food.y][food.x] = '*';
    }

}

public void draw(){
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            System.out.print(field[y][x]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

public Snake getSnake(){
    return snake;
}}
```

Snake.java

```
public class Snake{
public Point head;

public char direction;

public void init(int x, int y){
    this.head      = new Point();
    this.head.x    = x;
    this.head.y    = y;
    this.direction = 'w';
}
}
```

Point.java

```
public class Point{
int x;
int y; }
```

Comment: Here's a hint to make a huge leap as a Java developer - JavaScript has nothing to do with Java

Comment: Your tail could essentially be an ArrayList of Points. When you eat a pellet, you can add a new Point to the ArrayList. Set it up to draw these Points as it moves, updating each Point's values to be equal to the Point in front of it in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a List in your Snake class, where you will be storing it's length,
something like that

```
public class Snake{

   public Point head;
   public ArrayList array = new ArrayList(); // added ArrayList
   public char direction;

   public void init(int x, int y){
       array.add(3); // it will work if you want to count points or just simply add anything and count it's size with array.size()
       this.head      = new Point();
       this.head.x    = x;
       this.head.y    = y;
       this.direction = 'w';
   }
}
```